# xcode swift how to get user defaults but only what i entered

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile, nsuserdefaults

i am storing some data in the user defaults and when i am trying to print it out it will print out stuff that i did not specify. How do i print out only stuff that i entered.

this is what i get as result

```
asd:// = asd:// 

PKLogNotificationServiceResponsesKey = 0 

NSInterfaceStyle = macintosh 

asds:// = asds:// 

AKLastIDMSEnvironment = 0 

NSLanguages = (
    en
) 

AppleKeyboards = (
    "en_US@sw=QWERTY;hw=Automatic",
    "emoji@sw=Emoji",
    "en_US@sw=QWERTY;hw=Automatic"
) 

AppleLanguages = (
    en
) 

asd = dsdadsad 

AppleITunesStoreItemKinds = (
    eBook,
    artist
) 

asdasd = Another String Value 

ApplePasscodeKeyboards = (
    "en_US",
    emoji
) 

AddingEmojiKeybordHandled = 1 

adasdsad = adasdsad 

PKKeychainVersionKey = 8 

AppleKeyboardsExpanded = 1 

AppleLanguagesDidMigrate = 18D46
```

while all intered was the asd ones

my code for inserting these are:

```
@IBOutlet weak var testfield1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var testfield2: UITextField!
    
    
    @IBAction func testbutton1(_ sender: Any) {
        let appname: String = testfield1.text!
        var appinput: String = testfield2.text!
        appinput = appinput + "://"
        if appname == "" || appinput == "" {
            print("none")
        }
        else {
            let value = [
                appname,
                appinput
            ]
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            defaults.set(value[1], forKey: value[1])
        }
    }
```

and my code for getting it is :

```
for (key, value) in UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation() {
            print("\(key) = \(value) \n")
        
}
```

any ideas how i can get the ones that i made?
thanks in advance
if it is not possible can someone suggest something to save some data but only localy

Comment: You need to know. the keys that *you* have stored in `UserDefaults` and only retrieve those keys or you could use your own [suite name](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1409957-init), however if you want to save non-trivial amounts of data, use Core Data

Comment: thank you for responding so early and i will check it out :)